# Characterization of zero vectors with linear forms

Tags: modules

Let $M$ be a not necessarily free module over a commutative unital ring. True or false: if every linear form assigns to a vector of $M$ zero, then the vector is the zero vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Z/2$.